# Select query with unusual grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, select

There is a table with following data (i.e.):

`SELECT * FROM Fruits`

```
StartDate   EndDate     Information
------------------------------------
1992-09-01  1998-10-28  Cherry
1998-10-29  1998-12-30  Peach
1999-01-01  2000-01-31  Peach
2000-02-01  2000-06-30  Peach
2000-07-01  2001-01-31  Peach
2001-02-01  2002-03-31  Cherry
2002-04-01  2003-03-31  Carrot
2003-04-01  2003-05-20  Carrot
2003-05-21  2004-03-31  Apple
2004-04-01  2004-06-30  Apple
2004-07-01  2005-07-31  Apple
2005-08-01  2006-10-31  Apple
2006-11-01  2007-01-31  Apple
2007-02-01  2007-06-30  Apple
2007-07-01  2008-02-29  Apple
2008-03-01  2008-05-31  Apple
2008-06-01  2009-02-28  Apple
2009-03-01  2010-03-31  Apple
2010-04-01  2010-12-31  Apple
2011-01-01  2011-07-31  Apple
2011-08-01  2012-01-31  Apple
2012-02-01  2013-05-31  Apple
2013-06-01  2013-09-30  Apple
2013-10-01  2013-12-31  Apple
```

I have to make a query, that returns something like that:

```
StartDate   EndDate     Information
------------------------------------
1992-09-01  1998-10-28  Cherry
1998-10-29  2001-01-31  Peach
2001-02-01  2002-03-31  Cherry
2002-04-01  2003-05-20  Carrot
2003-05-21  2013-12-31  Apple
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want sequential values of each `information` in a single group.

You can do this by assigning a group number to the values.  One way to do this is by taking the difference of a sequential number over all the rows and a sequential number that restarts for each `information` value.  Then aggregate on this group:

```
select min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate, information
from (select f.*,
             (row_number() over (order by startdate) -
              row_number() over (partition by information order by startdate)
             ) as grp
      from fruits f
     ) f
group by grp, information;
```

Comment: I still cant understand how, but it works. Than you!